# Why SharedPreferences dont have isEmpty Method?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to check if sharedpref contains any keys without specifying what key it contains but it does not have any method `isEmpty`.

Map<String, ?> entries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
Set<String> keys = entries.keySet();

if (!keys.isEmpty()) {}

I was able to find a solution but is there a shorter solution? And why isEmpty method is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was able to find a solution but is there a shorter solution?

`entries.isEmpty()`, because [`Map` has `isEmpty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Map#isempty).

Comment: sharedPreferences.getAll().isEmpty()

Comment: found shorter anyways thanks